# How to use variable node-set in Xpath "contains()" function

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I want to check if node value  contains a string that occurs in an attribute of a node with-in variable made as a node-set.

```
<xsl:variable name="Var">
<root>
   <tag atr="x3"> some string <tag> 
   <tag atr="x4"> some string <tag>
<root>
<xsl:variable>
```

xml contains:

```
<name>one x3 two<name>
```

i've tried something like :

```
<xsl:value-of select="contains(name,msxsl:node-set($Var)/root/tag/@atr)"/>
```

but it just output's nothing and move on.

Comment: `contains()` accepts string arguments, so you can't pass it a nodeset. You need to check against every item in the nodeset individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath 1.0 if a function or operator expects a string and is passed a node-set, only the string value of the first (in document order) node of the node-set is produced and used by this function or operator.

Therefore, an expression such as:

```
contains(name, msxsl:node-set($Var)/root/tag/@atr)
```

tests only whether the string value of *the first* of the `msxsl:node-set($Var)/root/tag/@atr` nodes is contained in the string value of the first `name` node.

You actually want to see if the string value of *any* of the nodes in `msxsl:node-set($Var)/root/tag/@atr` is contained in a the string value of a given element, named `name`.

**One correct XPath expression evaluating this condition**:

```
boolean(msxsl:node-set($Var)/root/tag/@atr[contains($name, .)])
```

where `$name` is defined to contain exactly the element `name`.

**A complete code example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="name" select="'x42'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="Var">
   <root>
     <tag atr="x3"> some string </tag>
     <tag atr="x4"> some string </tag>
   </root>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "boolean(msxsl:node-set($Var)
              /root/tag/@atr[contains($name, .)])"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
true
```

**However, if we substitute in the above transformation the XPath expression offered in the another answer** (by Siva Charan) :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="name" select="'x42'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="Var">
   <root>
     <tag atr="x3"> some string </tag>
     <tag atr="x4"> some string </tag>
   </root>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "contains(name, msxsl:node-set($Var)/root/tag/@atr)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**this transformation produces the wrong answer**:

```
false
```

because it only tests for containment the first of all `attr` attributes.