# xpath to see if "current node" exists in external file nodeset attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, schematron

**Background**
I have a schematron validation and xslt translation to pdf.

**Problem**
I want to check if the content in an xml tag is present in a list of valid codes in an external file. only the attribute values in the external file are interesting. The node values are used for other purposes in another stylesheet.

```
<xsl:template match="//medicalFieldcode" priority="1000" mode="M4">
    <svrl:fired-rule xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl" context="//medicalFieldcode"/>
    <xsl:variable name="MVOcodes" select="document('verksamhetskodlista.xml')"/>

    <!--ASSERT -->
    <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="boolean($MVOcodes/module/document-merge/g-funcs/g[contains(@name,.)])"/>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <svrl:failed-assert xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
                            test="boolean($MVOcodes/module/document-merge/g-funcs/g[contains(@name,.)])">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">R43</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="location">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="schematron-select-full-path"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <svrl:text>MedicalFieldCode must be in the valid list of codes.</svrl:text>
            </svrl:failed-assert>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="M4"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The external file (verksamhetskodlista.xml) has the following structure:

```
<module xmlns:mmx="http://funx" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:fnc="http://funx/fnc" xmlns:att="http://funx/att" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<document-merge>
    <g-funcs>
        <g name="003">value1</g>
        <g name="009">another value</g>
        <g name="011">yet another value</g>
        <!-- ... -->
    </g-funcs>
</document-merge>
```

Extract from the sample xml:

```
<ProcessClaimSpecification xmlns="urn:riv:financial:billing:claim:ProcessClaimSpecificationResponder:1">
<s01:claimSpecification xmlns="urn:riv:financial:billing:claim:1" xmlns:s01="urn:riv:financial:billing:claim:ProcessClaimSpecificationResponder:1">
    <healthCareServicesSpecificationLine>
        <healthcarePerformed>
            <!-- a bunch of content --> 
            <activity>
                <medicalFieldCode>000</medicalFieldCode>
            </activity>
        </healthcarePerformed>
    </healthCareServicesSpecificationLine>
</s01:claimSpecification>
```

I need to validate this using xpath. 
I've tried applying this [contains instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589209/how-to-use-variable-node-set-in-xpath-contains-function?rq=1) w/o much luck, and I've been searching but to no avail.

The problem is that it always renders true, even when using 000 which is not in the list of codes. 
I've tried many different restructured varieties of the xpath contains but it's not working satisfactory. I'm not sure coming from the right angle here. I'm using xslt 2.0 so the variable should contain a nodeset.

Among others, I've tried these xpath expressions

```
boolean($MVOcodes/module/document-merge/g-funcs/g[contains(@name,.)])
contains($MVOcodes/module/document-merge/g-funcs/g/@name, .)
```

I've been at this for several days without getting anywhere so please help?
The external file is used in another xsl document as well, that's why it has this structure. I figured if I reuse it, it's less to maintain.

Comment: I think instead of `g[contains(@name,.)]` you want to compare `g[contains(@name, current()]`. The dot `.` in your attempt refers to the `g` element you have put the predicate on.

Comment: Thank you! You are correct, however, the validation still goes thru even if the value is not existent in the list of valid attribute values. Is there some logical error in the xpath expression that is evident, which I haven't found?

Comment: I am afraid I haven't understood the kind of validation that is supposed to go on, it is not clear. Try to reduce the problem to minimal but complete samples of XSLT and XML and wanted output and current output, to allow others to reproduce the problem. Given that at least some of your XML samples use various namespaces it is not clear at all what your XSLT match patterns match and your XPath expressions select at all without seeing any complete XSLT samples with namespace declarations (and `xpath-default-namespace` declarations?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tony Graham points out, the Xpath is probably possible to simplify using exists instead. And the type:o is also something I overlooked. The missing namespace in the context xpath is also true. Thanks for pointing out these things!

However, I discovered that there already was a rule for the same xml node higher up in the schematron file. I ended up adding another `<assert>` to that and it worked (along with some other changes).

This is what it looks like now in the schematron file:

```
<rule context="//urn2:activity/urn2:medicalFieldCode" flag="fatal">
    <assert id="R33" test="((count(../../urn2:diagnosis) = 0) and (count(../../urn2:treatment) = 0)) or not(starts-with(., '9'))">Diagnoser och åtgärder får ej förekomma när medicalFieldCode börjar med 9. Underlags-id: <value-of select="//urn1:claimSpecification/urn2:id"/></assert>
    <assert id="R43" test="boolean(document('verksamhetskodlista.xml')/module/document-merge/g-funcs/g[contains(@name, current()/text())])" flag="fatal">MedicalFieldCode must be in the valid list of codes.</assert>
</rule>
```

Which makes this the compiled XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="//urn2:activity/urn2:medicalFieldCode" priority="1007" mode="M3">
  <svrl:fired-rule xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
                   context="//urn2:activity/urn2:medicalFieldCode"/>

        <!--ASSERT -->
<xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="((count(../../urn2:diagnosis) = 0) and (count(../../urn2:treatment) = 0)) or not(starts-with(., '9'))"/>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <svrl:failed-assert xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
                            test="((count(../../urn2:diagnosis) = 0) and (count(../../urn2:treatment) = 0)) or not(starts-with(., '9'))">
           <xsl:attribute name="id">R33</xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:attribute name="location">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="schematron-select-full-path"/>
           </xsl:attribute>
           <svrl:text>Diagnoser och åtgärder får ej förekomma när medicalFieldCode börjar med 9. Underlags-id: <xsl:text/>
              <xsl:value-of select="//urn1:claimSpecification/urn2:id"/>
              <xsl:text/>
           </svrl:text>
        </svrl:failed-assert>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

        <!--ASSERT -->
<xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="boolean(document('verksamhetskodlista.xml')/module/document-merge/g-funcs/g[contains(@name, current()/text())])"/>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <svrl:failed-assert xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
                            test="boolean(document('verksamhetskodlista.xml')/module/document-merge/g-funcs/g[contains(@name, current()/text())])">
           <xsl:attribute name="id">R43</xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:attribute name="flag">fatal</xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:attribute name="location">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="schematron-select-full-path"/>
           </xsl:attribute>
           <svrl:text>MedicalFieldCode must be in the valid list of codes.</svrl:text>
        </svrl:failed-assert>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="M3"/>
</xsl:template>
```

According to my test files, this works as intended.

File intended to fail:

```
Result AnalyzeSchematronResult: MedicalFieldCode must be in the valid list of codes.
```

File intended to succeed:

```
Passed OK Schematronvalidate
```

Thanks again for your useful additions and helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a Schematron question, it might have been clearer if you'd posted the Schematron, not the XSLT that gets generated from the Schematron.  As it is, I worked with your XSLT, and I'll leave it to you to modify your Schematron to work the same way.

Firstly, your current XSLT matches on `medicalFieldcode`, not `medicalFieldCode`.  Note the `c` versus `C`.

Secondly, you probably need a namespace in the XPath for your context element.  In the example below, I use the `claim` prefix for the `urn:riv:financial:billing:claim:1` namespace URI.

Thirdly, `.` in an XPath means the current context (see https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#doc-xpath-ContextItemExpr).  So when you use `.` in `g[contains(@name,.)]`, the context is a `<g>` element, so you're comparing the string value of the element to the value of one of its attributes.  The usual thing to do when trying to use something from the original context inside a predicate is to declare and use a variable for the value that you want to use.  In Schematron, you'd use the `<let>` element.

Fourthly, `exists()` is a useful XPath 2.0 (and later) way to see if an XPath matches anything. I.e., if the XPath does not evaluate to an empty sequence (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-exists).

Lastly, yes, it's almost certainly a good idea to reuse an existing data file rather than have to maintain the same data two different ways.

The resulting modified XSLT, that I'll leave to you to turn back into Schematron, is:

```
<xsl:template match="//claim:medicalFieldCode" priority="1000">
    <svrl:fired-rule xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl" context="//medicalFieldcode"/>
    <xsl:variable name="MVOcodes" select="document('verksamhetskodlista.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="code" select="." />

    <!--ASSERT -->
    <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="exists($MVOcodes/module/document-merge/g-funcs/g[@name eq $code])"/>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <svrl:failed-assert xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
                            test="exists($MVOcodes/module/document-merge/g-funcs/g[contains(@name,.)])">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">R43</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="location">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="schematron-select-full-path"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <svrl:text>MedicalFieldCode must be in the valid list of codes.</svrl:text>
            </svrl:failed-assert>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="M4"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for very useful input on the matter and explaining further how schematron works! I will update with a comment on how I solved it.